# Iterating through a JavaScript array within an object

Tags: javascript

Why are all the values below returning as undefined?

```
for (var i = 0; i < object.array.length; i++) {
    $http.get(.....).success(function(...) {
        console.log(object.array[i]);    //returns undefined for each
    });
}
```

If I do this:

```
console.log(object.array[0]);
```

It shows the correct value in the array.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Code looks fine at first glance. Can you post the object/array you're trying to iterate over?

Comment: maybe your `for` loop is in scope, that don't have access to `object.array`

Comment: @AndrewEvt the loop is within the function which object is passed into..

Comment: Rather than stumbling around with a `console.log` torch, turn on the lights by using the debugger built into your browser. For one thing, that will show you the state of things **as it is right then**, with the JS engine paused. `console.log` will show you either how something *was* in the past, or sometimes how it **is** now, not when you logged it, and the rules around that are initially confusing. If you need to use `console.log` for this, log something static, e.g. `console.log(JSON.stringify(object.array[0]));`.

Comment: @user5222688 check your object, maybe you are trying to pass wrong object, or passed object haven't `array` property inside

Comment: @user5222688 If you do `console.log(object);` before doing the loop, what does get printed?

Comment: I am actually trying to use 'i' inside the .success(function(....)) of a $http.get... Could 'i' be out of scope here?

Comment: Yes. Your loop is continuing before your `.succes()` has completed. So if youre getting your object from your `$http` call then it hasnt returned when you try to log it.

Comment: Your code still seems incomplete. Why are you making `$http` calls in the middle of the loop? On another look it doesnt look like your object is depending on the calls so why are you logging it within the call?

Comment: `i` is not out of scope, as it is captured inside closure. But, because loop has already finished, its value point to index past the end of your array.

Answer (score 0):

You create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) that captures variable `i`. Most probably, that closure is not called right away, rather it is stored somewhere and executed at later time, when HTTP request finishes. At that time, your loop has already finished long ago, thus expression `i < object.array.length` no longer holds true. But the `i` variable inside closure is the very same variable that is defined inside `for` loop. So when code inside closure function is executed, `i` is equal to `object.array.length`, which is index that points to one element past the end of array. That's why you get `undefined`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < object.array.length; i++) {
    $http.get(.....).success(function(...) { // here you create closure
        console.log(object.array[i]);    // when this line executes, i is invalid
    });
}
```